# Three versions of Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, version, ubuntu-16.04

In case it is relevant, I am using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. I went to [install some software (Jupyter Notebook) which uses Python](http://jupyter.org/install), and the recommendation was to either use `python3 install` if I have Python 3, or `python install` if I am still using 2.7.

My Ubuntu installation came with both. `python --version` returns `2.7.12` and `python3 --version` returns `3.5.2`. However I also know that there is currently a Python 3.6 out there, which I installed... but it appears to use its own special reference `python3.6 --version` which returns `3.6.4`, whereas I had expected it to upgrade/replace `python3` so doing `python3 --version` would return `3.6.4`, but nope.

I'm not sure what the correct approach is here because apparently I shouldn't be messing with the Python versions that come installed since the OS may rely on them. At the same time it seems strange to install software that calls for Python3 even though it's going to be using 3.5 rather than 3.6.

Am I overthinking this? Is it expected behavior to use `python3.6` specifically for `3.6`-related features? Or do most people re-alias `python3` to redirect to `python3.6` instead? What about `pip`? `pip3`? Is there a `pip3.6`? I'm not entirely certain how I should be thinking about all these different Python installations.

Comment: I recommend you to use `virtualenv` to isolate the python develop environment between different projects.

Comment: like you said, Ubuntu 16.04 comes with python 3.5, that is why Ubuntu understands python3 as python 3.5, not python 3.6 and you are right you shouldn't be touching it (redirecting it by symlinking it, which shows up in your Ubuntu directory as `python3 <- python3.5`). in Ubuntu, you could either use Anaconda or virtualenv instead.

Comment: I subscribe virtualenv recommendation. About the several versions in the system (not in virtualenvs) I think there should be no problem in symlinking if the version major 3 number still applies to the new version (of course not doing it is even more safer)

Answer (score 2):

You may want to use virtualenv so you can control your python environment, it's good practice. With virtualenv you can specify which version to use and your libraries are installed only for the project that needs it.

Comment: What's the correct usage? Is it something I use only when installing something? Using it? How might I use it here in this example?

Comment: virtualenv is a pip package, basically you create a child of the python version you are running in a specified directory.
Then you can upgrade and do as you please as it does not affect the parent environment. You have millions of tutorials at your disposal and it is easy to use.
=> http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/

Answer (score 0):

You can use python2 and python3 alongside just fine. However, if you want to use different minor versions of the python, for example 3.4 and 3.6, you have to set up virtual environment for each version. Look for the virtualenv or other solution.